# Angular 2 deploy with SystemJS and Gulp is too heavy

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, systemjs

I've been developing with Angular for a while but I just started with Angular 2, and after finishing the quickstarter from the Angular 2 tutorial y thought about trying to develop the finished application in a server as in production mode.

I had no experience with SystemJS nor Gulp, so it took me a while, but I finally managed to make it work. Now I have 2 issues:

For a Hello World application, it's really heavy, about 20MB, because I had to download lots of files from Angular 2 libraries. My guess is I don´t really need so many, but although I started with only @angular/core and @angular/platform-browser-dynamic, which are the ones referenced in my application ts files, angular kept throwing error messages in deployment until I included the whole @angular library.

On the other hand, when I run the application I see again many single files being downloaded, which is not what I had in mind. There has to be a way to download only a single (minified) file with all the libraries (a bundle?) but I have no idea how to do that.

Can anyone give me a hand with that?

Here are my main configuration files.

system.config.js

```
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'lib/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic'
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(packIndex);

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="lib/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('babel-dp', ['resources', 'babel']);
gulp.task('ts-dp', ['resources', 'ts']);

gulp.task('resources', () => {
  gulp.src([
    'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web/lib'));

  gulp.src([
    'node_modules/@angular/**/*',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web/lib/@angular'));

  gulp.src([
    'node_modules/rxjs/**/*',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web/lib/rxjs'));

  gulp.src([
    'app/**/*.js'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web/app'));

  gulp.src([
    'styles.css'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web/css'));

  gulp.src([
    'index.html',
    'systemjs.config.js',
    'favicon.ico'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web'));
});

gulp.task('babel', () => {
    return gulp.src([
    'app/**/*.ts'
    ])
        .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
});

gulp.task('ts', function(done) {
  var tsResult = tsProject.src([
      'app/**/*.ts'
    ])
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));
  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
});
```

Let me know if you need any other file.
Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

I just found out that I can use the umd.min.js files inside @angular instead of the single js files. That is something, from 20 to 5MB, but still seems quite a lot, when the minified version of Angular 1 is less than 1MB.

On the other hand, even though I used these umd.min.js files, chrome is still downloading single files when loading the application.

**UPDATE 2**

I managed to create a single bundle file using systemjs-builder as suggested in the comments. Now I have a single file bundle.app.js with all my application code, and my index.html now looks like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="app/bundle.app.js"> </script>
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 2. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

but now chrome can´t find the js imported in html: shim.min.js, zone.js, Reflect.js and system.src.js.
I added a line in systemjs.config.js to include node_modules just in case, but I don´t think it's necessary. Anyway, it's not working either. Shouldn´t these imports be included in the bundle already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally got a working configuration, so I'll copy here all files needed in case somebody finds it helpful.

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart Deploy</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="lib/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system.src.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- 2. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <!-- application bundle -->
    <script src="app/bundle.app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

// systemjs-builder
const builder = new Builder('.', 'systemjs.config.js');

// typescript transpiler
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('babel-dp', ['resources', 'babel']);
gulp.task('ts-dp', ['resources', 'ts']);

gulp.task('bundle:app', () => {
  builder.buildStatic('app/*.js', 'web/app/bundle.app.js')
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Build complete');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error ' + err);
  })
})

gulp.task('resources', () => {
  gulp.src([
    'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web/lib'));

  gulp.src([
    'styles.css'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web/css'));

  gulp.src([
    'index.html',
    'favicon.ico'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('web'));
});

gulp.task('babel', () => {
    return gulp.src([
    'app/**/*.ts'
    ])
        .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
});

gulp.task('ts', function(done) {
  var tsResult = tsProject.src([
      'app/**/*.ts'
    ])
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));
  //return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});
```

The rest of the files have not changed.
The main points here for me are the use of systemjs-builder to create the bundle (thanks to @Thorsten for the hint) and the use of the bundle in the index.html.

Answer (score 1):

as for bundling several files / the libraries in single files, you can use gulp tasks.

Here is something to get you started. Be sure to understand what the different lines mean, might happen, you have to change some small pieces to reflect your needs.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const path = require('path');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
const paths = require('../paths');

gulp.task('bundle', cb => {
    runSequence(
        'bundle:app',
        'bundle:vendor',
        cb
    );
});

const app = 'app/**/*.js';
const specs = 'app/**/*.spec.js';

gulp.task('bundle:app', () => {
    const appModules = `[${app}] - [${specs}]`; // except specs
    return bundle(appModules, paths.dst + '/bundle.app.js', { baseUrl: paths.dst });
});

gulp.task('bundle:vendor', () => {
    // build app and remove the app code - this leaves only 3rd party dependencies
    const dstApp = path.join(paths.dst, app);
    const dstSpecs = path.join(paths.dst, specs);
    const vendorModules = `${dstApp} - [${dstApp}]`; 

    return bundle(vendorModules, paths.dst + '/bundle.vendor.js');
});

function bundle(src, dst, opt) {        
    const bundleOptions = Object.assign({
        baseUrl: '.',
        minify: false,
        sourceMaps: false,
        lowResSourceMaps: false, // mapping granularity is per-line instead of per-character
    }, opt);

    const Builder = require('systemjs-builder');
    const builder = new Builder(bundleOptions.baseUrl, paths.src + '/systemjs.config.js');

    return builder.bundle(src, dst, bundleOptions);
}
```

Minification is then additional step, but gulp-minify or gulp-uglify is worth a look.

Comment: hi @Thorsten Viel, I managed to create a bundle using a simplified version of your gulpfile, but I'm struggling with the imports in the index.html; i.e, I have now this `<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>` and the browser can´t find it, shouldn´t this already be included in the bundle?

Comment: The gulp bundles what is referenced in systemjs.config.js. Shim isn't a part of that usually. Same for zone or polyfills e.g. So it would be correct to use direct refs in your index.html for not bundled / packaged js.

Comment: As I cannot yet comment the question (low repu): 

"I just found out that I can use the umd.min.js files inside @angular instead of the single js files. That is something, from 20 to 5MB, but still seems quite a lot, when the minified version of Angular 1 is less than 1MB."

what are you importing? can you share yous systemjs.config.js? My bundle with several angular and 3rd party packages is only 1.6MB.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. My first update was without using a bundle, I was copying the umd.min.js files in node_modules to my deploy folder. Now my bundle is just about 2K, which is correct as it's basically a Hello World app.